# craft.matrixBlocks element queries with .type()

Tags: elementcriteriamodel, query, block-types

I'm using Craft Pro 3.0.0-beta.19 and I try to query matrix blocks with craft.matrixBlocks(). Background: I have event series (=structure) with a matrix block containing 1:n dates for each series. My block type in the "dates" matrix block is "eventDate" and looks like this: [image: Block Definition]

this works:

`{% set entries = craft.matrixBlocks() %}`

Since this is the first matrix block I have I get all the entries I have (2):

`{{ entries | length }}` will output: 2
`{{ entries.one().type }}` will output: eventDate

Good.

Now I want to limit the blocks to eventDate only

`{% set entries = craft.matrixBlocks.type('eventDate') %}`

On the first glance this seems to work, I get the same results.

But when I change this to

`{% set entries = craft.matrixBlocks.type('WhateverGoesHere') %}`

I still get the same results. Am i not understanding this or is it a bug?

Thanks,
Matthias

Comment: I really assume this is a bug. Also accessing the fields does not work, I posted an issue ticket on Github: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/1789

Comment: Curious if you get the same behavior on Craft 2 as well...

Comment: Did craft.matrixBlocks exist on Craft 2?

Comment: Duh... nope it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in a beta version of Craft 3 (fixed here: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/commit/9b6dad7385c5a82d1c83d230fe6ce0cfe940675b)